# MySQL v5.5 retrieve by a date range using a datetime column, but count a different column that crosses the date range

Tags: mysql

The output of the SQL retrieves an incorrect value for the call_count variable. I believe this is because the logdate variable can span more than one day, but the count I need is across those days. So I need a count of 7 for call_count even if the logdate is more than one day.

```
SELECT
    netID,
    logdate,
    netcall,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM NetLog sub
        WHERE sub.netID = NetLog.netID
        AND sub.logdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
        AND sub.logdate <= CURDATE()
    ) AS call_count,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT netID)
        FROM NetLog
        WHERE logdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
        AND logdate <= CURDATE()
    ) AS netID_count,
    logclosedtime
FROM NetLog
WHERE
    logdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
    AND logdate <= CURDATE()
GROUP BY netID, netcall
ORDER BY netID DESC;
```

The input data is complex but this comma delimited example is a subset.

```
"recordID","netID","logdate","logclosedtime"
"137584","9476","2023-07-10 23:58:36","2023-07-11 00:26:41"
"137611","9476","2023-07-11 00:03:28","2023-07-11 00:26:41"
"137605","9476","2023-07-11 00:02:43","2023-07-11 00:26:41"
"137614","9476","2023-07-11 00:03:34","2023-07-11 00:26:41"
"137588","9477","2023-07-11 00:00:01",NULL
"137587","9477","2023-07-10 23:59:50",NULL
"137590","9477","2023-07-11 00:00:24",NULL
"137591","9477","2023-07-11 00:00:30",NULL
"137586","9477","2023-07-10 23:59:43",NULL
"137585","9477","2023-07-10 23:59:19",NULL
"137589","9477","2023-07-11 00:00:11",NULL
```

When I run the code the call_count is 3 instead of 7, and 2 instead of 4.

I have tried everything I can think of including subsets within the SQL. I'm sure it could be done in two SQL programs but surely it can be done in one.

How do I restrict the date to the past 5 days but count the call_count within each netID? What would that SQL code look like?

Comment: note that mysql 5.5 reached end of life almost 5 years ago and has had no security updates in that time; it should be considered highly insecure.

Comment: Yes, thank you I am aware, but powerless to do anything about it just now.

Comment: Post the task itself completely. Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERRT INTO, not as CSV sample. Provide desired output for this data with detailed explanations.

Comment: Your `logdate` is DATETIME. So when you use `WHERE .. logdate <= CURDATE()` then you loose all rows which contains current date and non-zero timepart. Use `WHERE .. logdate < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: #Akina Thank you for giving me an answer not a lecture about out of date software or how to give example data. Not enough people are attempting to answer the question as opposed to degrade the person trying to figure out a problem, or get an answer to an issue. You are a breath of fresh air.